# Video skips in Ubuntu 10.10 when mouse is not moving

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, adobe-flash

hey, i have a dell inspiron 1545 (the one without web cam and so on), it originally had Vista, was "upgraded" to XP, and now has Ubuntu 10.10.

Before i installed 10.10 when I would watch a movie or a youtube video all was well and good, but since the change when my mouse is idle the video gets all wonky, it will skip, pause, move around, and so does the audio.

But when the mouse is moving all is well, any ideas? also, from time to time the mouse will freeze.

Comment: Why have you put the word 'communism' in the title?

Comment: its a word i use instead of expletives

Comment: Someone with editing power please change the title. That is not appropriate.

Comment: how do you figure? and if i can change it let me know, i will (im kinda new)

Comment: figured it out, sorry

Comment: Specific is even better. E.g. 'Ubuntu 10.10 video skips when mouse not moving'.

Answer (score 3):

In power management options turn off throttling the CPU.  This might be done in bios or power options.

Comment: thank you sir, have you any idea on the mouse freeze?

Comment: when the mouse is moving your desktop is "active" so it doesn't throttle the CPU.

Comment: it freezes randomly, as in, wont move, its an issue aside from the video skip/chopiness, i find that using the arrow keys or the tabs key unfreezes it, but only for a short while

Comment: mouse freezing, if cpu throttling doesn't fix it, I would ask a separate question on askubuntu.com  there are some devs on the site that might know far more than I

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this exact problem starting the kernel with the 'nohz=off' option:

```
nohz=   [KNL] Boottime enable/disable dynamic ticks
        Valid arguments: on, off
        Default: on
```

(source: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Instructions for grub2: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1366354

Relevant article: http://news.cnet.com/Linux-coders-tackle-power-efficiency/2100-1007_3-6192865.html